# How hide delete item in django admin TabularInline

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have admin view with tabular inline:

```
class AddressInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Address
    can_delete = False
    readonly_fields = ['kind']
    max_num = 3
    min_num = 3
    fields = (
       "kind", "country", "city", "post_code", "street", "no_house"
    )

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False


class CustomerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = (
        "first_name", "last_name", "pesel", "id_number", "birth_date",
        "photo"
    )
    inlines = [AddressInline]
```

I want form with three other inline form. This inline form always will be tree. I hide add another button. I don't want delete inline item button in form. How can I delete or hide this button? This button can't be show to user.

Comment: did you try to handle this with permissions in admin page?

Comment: Yes, but when I have create view delete button it is and user can delete inline form. I don't want that.